# Avoid repetitive calculations in columns? SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a table in SQL Server with this fiels:

t1(Amount, Tax, Extra, Option1, Option2, Option3)

I have a query like this:

```
Select 
(Amount/Tax*Extra)+Option1 as Value1,
(Amount/Tax*Extra)+Option2 as Value2,
(Amount/Tax*Extra)+Option3 as Value3
From t1
```

It's possible to precalculate (Amount/Tax*Extra) and use the precalculate value in all columns
like this:

```
Select
@pre_calculated_value+Option1 as Value1,
@pre_calculated_value+Option2 as Value2,
@pre_calculated_value+Option3 as Value3
```

Like a varible but for each column?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know what a computed column is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use a CTE as follows:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT (t1.Amount / t1.Tax * t1.Extra) AS [CalculatedValue],
          t1.Option1,
          t1.Option2,
          t1.Option3
   FROM t1
)
SELECT cte.[CalculatedValue] + Option1 AS [Value1],
       cte.[CalculatedValue] + Option2 AS [Value2],
       cte.[CalculatedValue] + Option3 AS [Value3],
```

This assumes that you only need this calculations in maybe just this, or relatively few, queries. You can use a computed column (persisted or non-persisted) if the calculation will be used in many / most queries. At that point, the difference between PERSISTED and non-PERSISTED is a trade-off between performance and diskspace: PERSISTED take up actual disk space but are only calculated upon INSERT and if any of the referenced columns change value, while non-PERSISTED are virtual columns that are calculated only upon being queried, but for every run of every query that they are referenced in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the "persistent" command during creation was the solution.

Ref.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/03/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and%C2%A0performance/

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if the value cannot be stored using a computed column, is to use a cross apply which, IMO, is more readable than the CTE version. e.g.

```
Select 
    a.val+Option1 as Value1,
    a.val+Option2 as Value2,
    a.val+Option3 as Value3
From t1 CROSS APPLY (SELECT Amount/Tax*Extra AS val) a
```